# Make a class usable only from another class

Tags: c#, inheritance

In my solution I have a project (DLL) which contains the following class:

```
public class cDB : IErrorExtender
{
    // Exception per le funzioni Static
    #region IErrorExtender members
    public ErrorList ErrorListMessages { get; set; }                        // ErrorList

    public bool IsInError                                                   // Errori?
    {
        get { return ErrorListMessages.Count > 0; }
    }
    #endregion

    public cLogger logger { get { return ErrorListMessages.TheLog; } }      // Logger

    private string ConnString { get; set; }                                 // Stringa di connessione
    private string DbName { get; set; }                                     // DB name

    public OleDbConnection Cnn;                                             // Oggetto connection
    public OleDbTransaction _trans { get; private set; }                    // Oggetto per transazione ole

    /// <summary>
    /// Costruttore
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cnn"></param>
    /// <param name="connectDb"></param>
    /// <param name="theLog"></param>
    public cDB(OleDbConnection cnn, bool connectDb, cLogger theLog)
    {
        Cnn = cnn;
        DbName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(cnn.DataSource);
        ErrorListMessages = new ErrorList(theLog, LoggingTypes.OnlyErrors, this.ToString());

        this.ConnString = cnn.ConnectionString;
        if (connectDb)
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionOpen();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                ErrorListMessages.SetInternalError(exc, "cDB()");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Test()
    {}
}
```

As it's public, in the main projects there're lots of references to it (please consider that's a legacy project):

```
Engine.cDB dbo = new Engine.cDB();
```

Now, in the main project I've a class with a reference of cDB:

```
public class cDataBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public cDB DBO { get; }    
}
```

Basically what I would want, is the class cDB must be usable only thru an instante of cDataBase class, so somethig like:

```
cDataBase.DBO.Test();
```

and not by creating an istance as I written above. Any helps?

Comment: Define a public interface and make the class itself a private member of `cDatabase` and it implements the public interface. Expose the instance as interface.

Comment: I'm pretty confused, what are you meaning with make the class itself? which one?

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to make the constructor of the cDB-Class internal, so it can only be used inside the same project / class library:

```
public class cDB : IErrorExtender
{
    internal cDB() { }
}
```